# SELECT INTO from table works but from view fails

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, view

I Have a sproc which selects fields into a data table. 
I have a source table and have created a view pointing to the same source table. When I run the sproc using the table as the source, all works as expected, but when I run the sproc using the view as the source, nothing works.

Any pointers as to what I am missing will be a help.
Thanks Bill

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @TheID + ' as cardID 
            INTO ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + ' 
            FROM ' + @FromTab;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

When `@FromTab` is a table, it works but when `@FromTab` is view it fails.

```
SET @itemProvision = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @PV_TempPivotItems +
```

When I try to Alter the new table created from a source table, it works as expected but when I try to Alter the new table when created using the view as the source, I get table not found.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name
          FROM   sysobjects
          WHERE  name = @PV_TempPivotItems
                 AND xtype = 'U')
  BEGIN
      EXEC('drop table ' + @PV_TempPivotItems)
  END

SET @SQL ='SELECT ' + @TheID + ' as cardID 
           INTO ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
           FROM ' + @FromTab;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

SET @itemProvision = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
        ADD
        CardName varchar(50),
        CardDescription varchar(max),
        CardHref varchar(250),
        CardImage varchar(250),
        CONSTRAINT PK_PV_TempPivotItems PRIMARY KEY(cardID)
        ;'

EXEC sp_executesql @itemProvision;
```

Comment: `SELECT INTO` creates a new table.  How do you expect to create a table and `SELECT` from it (via the view) in the same query?

Comment: Can't debug invisible code. sorry.

Comment: Dan:  The sproc creates the new table from a source table, but the sproc fails to create the new table when using a view as the source.

Comment: what is the error message ??

Comment: M.Ali: When I try to Alter the new table created from a source table, it works as expected but when I try to Alter the new table when created using the view as the source, I get table not found.

Comment: Thanks pyNoob: I need to go (my wife).... I will give it a try later.  Many thanks.  Bill

Comment: @pyNoob - That isn't correct. The only `@` are regular variables as the OP is using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Please post a *full* example that we can run that reproduces the issue you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

**Found the problem**
I was dynamically obtaining the primary key from the source data as supplied via the @FromTab parameter , and using the returned field to SET the @TheID parameter which would then be utilised in other queries.
A primary-key field name was returned when the source is a Table, but nothing was returned when the source was a View. Needless to say, the subsequent queries which depended on @TheID parameter failed to execute.

Many thanks to **pyNoob** for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the below scripts, and each works as expected. Script A is using the physical table as the source for the first dynamic table creation.  Script B is using the view as the source table creation.

Both execute successfully and produce the same output. Please see below.

**SCRIPT A | Physical Table as Source**

```
GO
--CREATE PHYSICAL TABLE FOR TEST
CREATE TABLE dbo.testdata (COL_A INT NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO testdata
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)



--TEST DYNAMIC SQL TABLE CREATION USING PHYSICAL TABLE
GO
DECLARE @PV_TempPivotItems NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.newtable'
DECLARE @FromTab NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.testdata'
DECLARE @TheID NVARCHAR(50) = 'COL_A'


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(255)
SET @SQL ='SELECT ' + @TheID + ' as cardID 
           INTO ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
           FROM ' + @FromTab;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;


-- TEST ALTER TABLE WITH PHYSICAL TABLE
GO 
DECLARE @PV_TempPivotItems NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.newtable'
DECLARE @itemProvision NVARCHAR(255)
SET @itemProvision = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
        ADD
        CardName varchar(50),
        CardDescription varchar(max),
        CardHref varchar(250),
        CardImage varchar(250),
        CONSTRAINT PK_PV_TempPivotItems PRIMARY KEY(cardID)
        ;'

EXEC sp_executesql @itemProvision;
```

**SCRIPT B | View as Table Creation Source**

```
GO
--CREATE PHYSICAL TABLE FOR TEST
CREATE TABLE dbo.testdata (COL_A INT NOT NULL)


INSERT INTO testdata
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)


--CREATE VIEW FROM PHYSICAL TABLE
GO
CREATE VIEW card_view
as
SELECT * FROM dbo.testdata


--TEST DYNAMIC SQL TABLE CREATION USING VIEW
GO
DECLARE @PV_TempPivotItems NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.newtable'
DECLARE @FromTab NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.card_view'
DECLARE @TheID NVARCHAR(50) = 'COL_A'


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(255)
SET @SQL ='SELECT ' + @TheID + ' as cardID 
           INTO ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
           FROM ' + @FromTab;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;


-- TEST ALTER TABLE WITH PHYSICAL TABLE CREATED FROM VIEW
GO 
DECLARE @PV_TempPivotItems NVARCHAR(50) = 'dbo.newtable'
DECLARE @itemProvision NVARCHAR(255)
SET @itemProvision = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @PV_TempPivotItems + '
        ADD
        CardName varchar(50),
        CardDescription varchar(max),
        CardHref varchar(250),
        CardImage varchar(250),
        CONSTRAINT PK_PV_TempPivotItems PRIMARY KEY(cardID)
        ;'

EXEC sp_executesql @itemProvision;
```

**RESULT**

[image: RESULT]

Comment: I drop the tables if they exist.  I pass-in the params. If the param is table name, it works. If the param is a view name it fails.

Comment: Not following what you're doing with the alter table. I thought you were just selecting from a view and inserting into another table.  Can you post the code you used to create the view. And then the fully altered dynamic SQL and error msg?

Comment: SELECT        recordID, Category, CardImage, CardDescription, CardHref, CardTitle
FROM            dbo.myTable

Comment: I first create the new table from the source table and then alter the new table to add additional fields as required. based upon params supplied by user

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if i had the full code. Are you able to post it or is it confidential?